# How to Create Angled Screenshots of Mobile Screen on Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app

Anyone know of an easy way to create angled Mobile Screenhots on Sketch 3 like the image below?

Pretty sure if I transform the image to proper angles and add shadows I can do the same thing but I was wondering if there was some type of automatic 'Skew' technique like in Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: It's not "automated" in Photoshop. [You have to manually do it](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect)

Comment: @Scott i meant automated as in 'Smart Objects'. There are quite a few templates for photoshop for those.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to skew something in Sketch or are you trying to locate a template??

Comment: If there are any templates I would rather try those definitely. I assume skewing something in Sketch is just done by the 'transform' button? Alternatively is there any kind of perspective grid to help when transforming?

Comment: This is an answer I gave to a somewhat related question here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38913/skew-transform-severely-distorts-screenshot-any-workaround/38922#38922

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Magic Mirror](http://magicmirror.design/) plugin for Sketch to easily create perspective mockups in Sketch. Here's a detailed tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7wOPtKjVps

Comment: (In response to the notice about not giving a one-line answer) Well, there are two ways I can approach this:

1. Provide links to the plugin that will let you do this, and a link to a video tutorial that explains the process in detail.

2. Try and write the process step-by-step here. 

I'm assuming the second approach is a waste because lines of text will not come close to the explanation in the video, and hence will be a worse answer than the one I have as of now.

Comment: Its a automated answer that has been vetted by 5 persons. This webpage site is supposed to be as self contained as possible. So while you can link to the video. You should still do 2. The second approach is definitely not waste, text is much faster to follow than watching a video which mostly is waste of time. As generating answers here is the central purpose of the site its never wasted, just linking out is wasted as far as stackexchange is concerned. It could be worse your answer could have been deleted altogether.